"In sober fact" meaning
What does  "in sober fact" mean.
I know that "in fact", is used to emphasize the truth of something, especially when it may seem contrary.
However, adding sober must somehow change the meaning. What is it?
The phrase is from the book The Daughter of time by Josephine Tey

The Midget was Nurse Ingham, and she was in sober fact a very nice five feet two, with everything in just proportion.

Also, does anyone know about this book? I just randomly started reading it.

I'm so glad you're reading it! It was my gateway into Ricardianism, a band of, let's be honest, geeks with a niche obsession for insisting that the image of Richard III as a bloodthirsty hobgoblin popularized by Shakespeare was a political smear job and he was actually rather a nice guy. I remember little about the book except that it did a rather readable job of framing the question as a bit of a detective story. Be advised that plenty of historical evidence has been turned up since it was written, including finding Richard's body! I get the perception that...

... the Ricardian position has also grown a bit in the public eye lately, and is less fringe and better publicized.

Hi, it's me from Meta. All these random bounties are not doing you a favour; however angry you feel, you're just making it worse for yourself. You are in fact drawing negative attention to yourself, if I were I'd apologise to the mods on Meta, —you should have received a message in your inbox—and ask them (politely) to undo the bounties across the network. Accept the loss of reputation as a punishment. But in the end, it's your account, your life.

OED defines it as:

1619–
Moderate, sensible; free from exaggeration; not fanciful or imaginative.

How much or how little of sober fact there may be in those thrilling incidents..it is impossible to say.
(A. Jessopp, Coming of Friars iv. 169)


PowerThesaurus gives a long list of synonyms for in sober fact among which

in point of fact
in all honesty
frankly speaking  in actual fact etc.


I believed to be: an emphasis for "in fact", which itself is an emphasis. You quote "sober fact"; "in sober fact", would it also have the same meaning as you quote. Or does it have to do with "in fact"?

"In fact" expresses surprise, contrast with what you would normally expect (she was unexpectedly nice). "In sober fact" is a claim to "honest truth", not a surprise. "She was really nice, and I am not embellishing facts."

I understand. Thank you.

But also, is the combination of in fact and sober fact, that is, in sober fact, any different from the latter.

"The Midget" is a humorous exaggeration of the nurse's short stature. In fact, 5'2" (roughly 1.57 metres) is by no means unusually small for a British woman.

latter: sober fact

@KateBunting >Grant called her The Midget to compensate himself
for being bossed around by a piece of Dresden china which he could pick up in one
hand... The book says that. Also your reason fits in.

@ApoorvaShukla It might help to understand "in fact" not just as an intensifying phrase, but in its literal meaning, "speaking with a grounding in objective facts." E.g. "You might suppose that an animal as large as the blue whale eats large food, but in fact it eats tiny krill." It is a "fact" that it eats krill, and we are distinguishing that from the mistaken fantasy. Adding the adjective "sober" doesn't alter this pattern.

Well if you take the noun "fact" and put the preposition "in" in front of it, you have the same effect. It becomes a discourse marker.

@ApoorvaShukla It could be understood a bit like a witnesses' legal testimony; they're not only asserting that they're telling the truth ("in fact") but that they are clear-headed and taking the matter seriously, not jesting. This is especially apropos since "The Midget" is a tongue-in-cheek nickname.

@KateBunting The speaker might have said that, because he's six foot odd (mentioned in the book) and therefore 5 feet 2 inch may seem to him small but this does not imply that 5" 2' is small for any women in the absolute sense.

Exactly. She's humorously described as a midget but in sober fact she is merely near the lower end of the normal range of heights. (I'm 5'1" myself.)
